# Looking for a way to convert an iOS phonegap plugin to an Android phonegap plugin

Tags: android, ios, plugins, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I would like to convert iOS MapKit plugin to Android.

Does anyone have any resources around converting a plugin from one platform to another?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well the JavaScript should be portable but the Objective-C code will have to be re-written in Java for Android.